# How do you check if inputted array values are the same?

Tags: java

My program is supposed to make sure each value the user enters is between 10-100. The value is then stored in the array. That part works fine. The other condition is that the value the user enters has to be different from all the other arrays. ie...array[0]=20 so all of the other arrays can no longer equal to be set to 20. I've been trying to solve this but I'm just not sure where to go. I tried setting statements after my while(userInput < 10 || userInput > 100) to check for any repeats and that worked. The problem was then the user could enter values less than 10 and greater than 100. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creating scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[5];
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter < 5)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number between 10 & 100: ");
            int userInput = input.nextInt();

            while(userInput < 10 || userInput > 100)
            {                
                System.out.print("Please enter number between 10 & 100: ");
                userInput = input.nextInt();
            }

            array[x] = userInput;
            System.out.println(array[x]);
            counter++;

        }

    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The value of Array[0]: " + array[0]);
    System.out.println("The value of Array[1]: " + array[1]);
    System.out.println("The value of Array[2]: " + array[2]);
    System.out.println("The value of Array[3]: " + array[3]);
    System.out.println("The value of Array[4]: " + array[4]);        

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the for and second while loop, and check if the value entered is in the desired range.

If it is, you verify for duplicates, store it in the array and increment the counter. If it’s not, you show the bad input message.

Either way, it continues to ask for an valid input until the counter gets to 5.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I changed your logic a little bit, see if you can understand it
(There are better ways of doing this, but I think this is more understandable)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creating scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[5];
        int counter = 0;

        while(counter < 5)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number between 10 & 100: ");
            int userInput = input.nextInt();

            if(userInput < 10 || userInput > 100)
            {                
                System.out.print("Please enter number between 10 & 100.\n");
            }
            else {
                //This is a valid input, now we have to check whether it is a duplicate
                boolean isItDuplicate = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                {
                    if(userInput == array[i])
                    {
                        isItDuplicate = true;
                    }
                }
                if(isItDuplicate == true)
                {
                    System.out.print("Please enter a number that is not a duplicate.\n");
                }
                else 
                {
                    array[counter] = userInput;
                    System.out.println(array[counter]);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The value of Array[0]: " + array[0]);
        System.out.println("The value of Array[1]: " + array[1]);
        System.out.println("The value of Array[2]: " + array[2]);
        System.out.println("The value of Array[3]: " + array[3]);
        System.out.println("The value of Array[4]: " + array[4]);        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use variable `counter` when var `x` does the same thing for you.
2. Don't use nested loops when the limiting condition of both loops need to be checked **together** in each iteration. Merge those loops into one wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get rid of your nested loops.  They're redundant.  Let's look at your problem's specification.  Your input needs to fulfill 3 requirements:

- Be greater than or equal to 10
- Be less than or equal to 100
- Be a unique element inside the array

The first  two conditions are simple enough to check.  For the final condition, you need to search the values inside the array and see if there are any matches to your input.  If so, the input is invalid.  A simple way to approach this is to check every member of the array and to stop if a duplicate is found.  There are better, more efficient ways to do this.  Don't be afraid to search the internet to learn a searching algorithm.  Below is a simple solution to your problem.  It's far from ideal or efficient, but it's easy enough for a beginner to understand.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[5];
        int counter = 0;
        int userInput;

        while(counter < 5) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 10 & 100: ");
            userInput = in.nextInt();
            if( (userInput >= 10 && userInput <= 100) && !searchDuplicates(array, userInput) ) {
                array[counter] = userInput;
                counter++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid value entered");
            }
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
           System.out.println("Value " + (i + 1)  + ": " + array[i]);
    }

    private static boolean searchDuplicates(int[] array, int input) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            if(array[i] == input)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```